# Is This A Colour Sensor?

Tags: sensors

[image]
[image]

Hi Iam new to robotics and stack exchange and Iam 13 years old,this is a IR sensor, can you tell me that  is this thing have a colour sensor on it?

Comment: what research have you done? ... please add a picture of the other side of the device

Comment: @jsotola I have a kit of robonxt and I have other parts like this and Iam trying to make a robot but I can't program it like I want to so I doubt that I have a right part the book says that this is a IR sensor and it can also follow coloured lines so I doubt that this has a colour sensor.

Comment: why did you not say that it is an infrared sensor in your question? ... most people here do not know what the device is and may waste time researching something that you already know ... please add as much information as you can to your question

Comment: infrared (IR) is just a shade of red that we cannot see .... do an experiment ... find a red filter, such as a red glass, or a red bottle and look through it ... are you able to see coloured lines?

Comment: @jsotola Okay.....thnx

Comment: I tried it but I was not able to see any coloured lines I also tried to do as you told with another IR light that I have but nothing happened I could not see any coloured lines

Comment: are you saying that you looked through a red filter and you could not see any lines?

Comment: @jsotola yes, I can't.I looked through a red bottle.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Muaviyah Arsalan. On stack exchange, it is better to edit your question to add information requested in comments, rather than adding more comments. Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. If all of the information needed to answer the question is contained within it, the comments can be tidied up (deleted).

Comment: @MarkBooth thanks I will make sure that I do as you told.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is just IR sensor. This sensor wont able to differentiate color between red, green,blue etc. But you can use this sensor to differentiate black line and white floor (in case u wanna build line follower) because if it was white floor it will reflect more infrared transmitted from this device to its photodiode. U can see the infrared by turning on this sensor and look through your phone camera. You will see purple light.

If you wanna sense another color. You need color sensor. Just google it.

Hope this help :)

Comment: but when I use this sensor it works on everything and colour except black.can you please tell me why does this happen?

Comment: And it also has a photo detecteor

Comment: How do you define "it works"? That sensor measure intensity of IR light transmitted by itself (and another source if it available such us sun).

Comment: it sense everything except the colour black, if something has a black colour it doesn't sense it

Comment: Could you tell more about what kind of value you get when it sense other color and when it sense black?

Comment: it has a light attach  on it when it sense something the light turn on, the light does not turn on when it sense black although Iam not so sure that it really sense black

Comment: Ok i got it. Then you have a proximity sensor which only give you 1(light on) and 0(light off). If black give you 0, its because the infrared light detected by photodiode didnt pass the threshold (because most of IR absorbed by object).

Comment: Thank you very much you have solved my problem.....Thanks again.

Comment: Your welcome! Keep learning!